# How to replace "value" in Javascript with Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have three kind of HTML coming either of them:

```
<input name="myName" id="myID" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;" type="text" value="SDFSF"/>
```

OR

```
<input name="myName" id="myID" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;" type="text" value='SDFSF'/>
```

OR

```
<input name="myName" id="myID" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;" type="text"/>
```

I don't know which of them coming. I am trying to edit them like this:

```
<input name="myName" id="myID" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;" type="text" value=''/>
```

I am using this thing:

```
html = html.replace(/value="(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"/,"value=''");
```

This is able to replace `value="Something"` to `value=''`. How can I extend this for other two? Is there any option for `OR` in Javascript?

**Edit**

I don't have the DOM element. So, I have to use it like this.

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions, when you could use the DOM to do this more easily and more reliably?

Comment: Why, oh why?! You already have HTML - just use the DOM to manipulate it! `document.getElementById("myID").value = ""`

Comment: @Aleks: `getElementById` only works tough if the element is part of the document. If the OP gets the data as HTML string, that won't work. There are, however, other and equally easy ways.

Comment: I have the HTML only. I don't have the DOM element when I am replacing it.

Comment: @FelixKling I highly doubt that the OP is getting HTML as strings to be processed with javascript.

Comment: Further to my original comment (and similar, if not identical, to Felix's answer): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rmb79/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the HTML into a DOM element and manipulate it. Then you can convert it back to HTML or whatever you want to do with it:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;
container.firstChild.setAttribute('value', '');

html = container.innerHTML;
```

---

**Note:** Others mentioned to use `element.value = '';`. This works as long as you don't want to serialize the element back to HTML. If you did, it would still have the original `value` value.

Answer (score 1):

Please use simply the DOM

```
document.getElementById("myId").value = "";
```

you can also refer to the previous value to check.

```
var el = document.getElementById("myId")
var myValue = el.value;

if (myValue === notSoGood) {
    el.value = "BetterValue";
}
```